# How to register user without admin in ROS?

Tags: realm

Now I'm verification ROS2.0 with NodeJS
But I don't know How to register user without admin in ROS2.0 from NodeJS.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can register a user, so you can just following the guidelines here: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#users

```
Realm.Sync.User.register('http://my.realm-auth-server.com:9080', 'username', 'p@s$w0rd', (error, user) => { /* ... */ });
```